# Adapt Eclipse PHP code formatter for Symfony coding standards

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

How do I adapt Eclipse PHP code formatter for [Symfony coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html)?

Especially I want to get rid of [spaces around concatenation operator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#structure) which the code formatter adds with any of default profiles as of writing.

```
$a = $b->bar.'*'.$c->baz; // not $b->bar . '*' . $c->baz
```

Code formatter allows to [export and import a profile in XML](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sanmai/aac37a86fff415920e9ed4c8b7d75ab5/raw/ac9a2d230b4c5f2aab568d89e3c85f09af5c1dc5/Symfony.xml), but it isn't clear which directive in it is responsible for the above spaces.

---

See this [slightly modified PSR-2 profile](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/aac37a86fff415920e9ed4c8b7d75ab5) I used as a starting point, without success.

Comment: Don't know how to do this in eclipse but if you use git as a version control, you can take advantage of some pre-commit hooks that will fix that for you (take a look to [cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)) or you can even run it manually

Comment: @DonCallisto  cs-fixer is fine and good, but can I have this done from the IDE too?

Comment: I really don't know, I use PHPStorm (that, to me, is far better) :) btw I really don't know even how to have it directly in PHPStorm but is safer to have  a fixer as you can always modify yourself the base template of your ide

Comment: can you open bugs on Symfony Eclipse Plugin or on PDT directly?

Comment: @zulus doesn't seem like a bug for me...

Comment: If documentation, option is unclear it's a bug. If you option you need not exists, fill a bug and mark as enhancement ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your profile configuration, whitespace tab, you need to uncheck :
Before operator > Binary operator
After operator > Binary operator

Sadly, this does not affect only the concatenation operator on string, other operator will be also without spaces.

The purpose of a formater is to have all operators with the same format, so this make sense because [the dot is an operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) according to the docs.

Comment: Can't accept this cause I need spaces around other operators left intact.

Comment: I found myself with the same dilemma

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is not possible without editing source. You can rather change source code your self or ask a feature request to make it happened, which no one knows if someone will do it.

Here are editable preferences and I don't see anywhere that.

https://github.com/eclipse/pdt/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.php.formatter.core/src/org/eclipse/php/formatter/core/CodeFormatterPreferences.java

Comment: Well, probably I would have to find out how does one builds Eclipse PDT from source... Only if I could avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Eclipse, however, this should work:

According to Symfony's [coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html):

> Symfony follows the standards defined in the PSR-0, PSR-1, PSR-2 and PSR-4 documents.

That means you just need to find a PSR code formatter for Eclipse.

Here's an Eclipse formatter for PSR:

- https://github.com/wcomnisky/php-formatter

I've also used a non-Eclipse tool which runs on Linux: The [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/). It is pretty neat and includes Symfony support.

[Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfPhp/PHP-CS-Fixer) shows that something like this should work:

```
$ php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --rules=@Symfony
```

And, a little more digging led me to discover an Eclipse plugin that includes the [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](https://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs), in case you don't want to just use the command line.

Comment: I'll check it, but so far it look just same as I use - which does add spaces around concatenation operators.

Comment: I linked to an Eclipse plugin which bundles cs-fixer. Good luck regardless.

Comment: Oh well. See, cs-fixer works with whole files in all reincarnations. Where embedded code formatter can fix just parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely won't think it's an answer, but posting it anyway.

Symfony coding standards won't change a thing to how your project works, nor does it will make it faster if you follow it.
In the end, it's your server that doing the job, and it accept PHP no matter how it's formated as long as there is no error.

Structude coding standard is mostly here to make it easy for you to read your code, and help you avoid basic mistakes.

Naming convention, services included, is a basic in any PHP project.

And you will notice soon enough that no matter what, you have to use PHPDoc (ex: [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html))

In the end, it doesn't matter if you write `if (1==1)` or `if(1 == 1)`, nor does placing open braket on the next line (I keep it on the same line).
So long that your code is clean and you can easily understand it, it's what matter the most.
Except if you're like someone I know and code everything on a single line (true story), then you're screwed.

Regarding your question, Eclipse just isn't flexible enough to do what you want.
And it most likely never will, because it's free, no-one is paid to dev it.

I spent a few years finding a good IDE...
And I will advice you with the same advice I got 2 years ago, and that some others will suggest as well, use [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) from [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/).

If you happen to be a student or a teacher, you can get it for free.
Else, you will have to pay for it, but to be honest, the individual customers licence is quite cheap/year.

I will also add that having a good and complete IDE will help you improve your bad coding habits.
I'm sure that most of PhpStorm users can't count the number of bad habits they corrected with PhpStorm inspections tool.

Hope you will find this answer satisfying.